# Text Classification + Naive Bayes + Scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am going to do Text classification first time with Naive Bayes.
This code I found on http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html :

```
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
>>> clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
```

I want to resolve one doubt about the parameters `X_train_tfidf`, `twenty_train.target` passed to the function fit().

X_train_tfidf is the tfidf vector representation of all the documents in the train set.

twenty_train.target is the corresponding labels of documents **in the exact order** as they appear in the X_train_tfidf set.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: This is true for every **fit** method you will find using the API. Given a **matrix** of documents **X** with dimensions [m, n], the target **vector Y** will have dimension [n, 1] and **document X[:, j] matches target Y[j] for every j from 0 to n-1**.

If documents and targets don't match you will probably get a very poor and unreasonable result from your training process.

Comment: Is there any problem according to Scikit learn documentation if Y is of dimension [1, n] according to scikit learn documentation?

Comment: Never looked for it but in a quick test I got this warning message:
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel()